# How do I pass variables to functions while adding them into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time a th-element is clicked a function with variable (the text of the clicked th-element) is stored in an array.
However, rather than the value (1,2 or 3 etc.), the name of the variable is stored("column").

How do I store that value rather than the variable name?

In the example below you will see that in the console that the variable-name "column" is stored each time a th-element is clicked.

```js
var recordedFunctions = [];
$(document).on("click", "th", function() {
  var column = this.innerHTML;
  recordedFunctions.push(function() {sel(column)});
  console.log(recordedFunctions.toString());
  alert(column);
});

function runRecordedActions() {
  console.log(recordedFunctions.toString());
  for (i = 0; i < recordedFunctions.length; i++) {
    recordedFunctions[i]();
  }
}

function sel(v) {
  alert(v);
}
```

```css
table th {
  height: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #757575;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<br>

<button type="button" onClick="runRecordedActions()">RUN</button>
```

Comment: what do you expect exactly? while clicking run button you want to see all the ways stored on the array?

Comment: The code works. when the "run" button is hit, the correct values are shown in an alert-box. In the code I am working on however this part does not work, but I was unfortunately unable to reproduce it here. There seems to be a conflict somewhere else in the code. I hoped to solve this by storing the variable outcome as values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your loop and your function too. I added a test() and push it into an array.
Here is working code:

```
var recordedFunctions = [];
function test(column) {
    return column;
}
$(document).on("click", "th", function() {
  var column = this.innerHTML;
  recordedFunctions.push(test(column));

  alert(recordedFunctions);
  console.log(recordedFunctions.toString());
  alert(column);
});

function runRecordedActions() {

  for (var key in recordedFunctions) {

    console.log(recordedFunctions[key]());
  }
}

function sel(v) {
  alert(v);
}
```

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal when click run, what should happen?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I edited my answer. You should remove this line recordedFunctions[i]();  too, because recordedFunctions[i]() is not a function. It is an array.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal correct if am wrong. Requirement is clicked(ex 1, 2 and 3) values should show in console when click run. is it so?

Comment: I run it on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdVZoE. It is working.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal What I understood that he just want to store value when clicking on the button and getting it back when clicking on Run button.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal okay, I edited my answer as per his need. Thanks.

Comment: @Sanchit is correct I need both the function and variable to be pushed into an array. In the project I am working on other functions will be added to the array as well

Answer (score 0):

Something strange, In stackoverflow snippet, not able get the values stores in
`recordedFunctions` array, where we can get the values outside in [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/43d4tazy/1/). Check below snippet as well as the fiddler, which gives all clicked values when trigger `run` button.

```js
var recordedFunctions = [];
$(document).on("click", "th", function() {
  var column = this.innerHTML;
  recordedFunctions.push(function() {sel(column)});
  console.log(recordedFunctions[recordedFunctions.length-1].toString());
  alert(column);
});

function runRecordedActions() {
  var output='Values are:';
  for (i = 0; i < recordedFunctions.length; i++) {
    output += (' ' + recordedFunctions[i].toString());
  }
  alert(output);
}

function sel(v) {
  alert(v);
}
```

```css
table th {
  height: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #757575;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<br>

<button type="button" onClick="runRecordedActions()">RUN</button>
```